# REST endpoint to access an item stored inside DynamoDB

Tags: rest, amazon-dynamodb

I have a dynamo table storing an item with the primary and secondary keys as follows:

pk: Parent#{parent_id}

sk: Child#{child_id}.

This means when designing a GET endpoint to retreive the child, I need both the parent id and the child id, resulting into something like: `/api/children/{parent_id}/{child_id}`.

For some reason, this doesn't feel right to me. Is this a bad practise?

Answer (score 1):

It's not necessarily bad. For example, with Amazon S3 the bucket is the parent and the key is the child. And here's one way how S3 exposes access:

`https://s3.Region.amazonaws.com/bucket-name/key-name`

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/access-bucket-intro.html